# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /u/applic/wsadmin/geronimo217/geronimo8/var/catalina/work/TomcatWebContainer/SESSIONS.ser (Permission denied)

Tags: java, tomcat, geronimo

I am facing 
ERROR [ManagerBase] IOException while saving persisted sessions: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /u/applic/wsadmin/geronimo217/geronimo8/var/catalina/work/TomcatWebContainer/SESSIONS.ser (Permission denied)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the file? Chances are you don't have read permissions on it. More specifically the user that the code is running as doesn't have permssions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.io.FileNotFoundException (permission denied) despite chmod 777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008976/java-io-filenotfoundexception-permission-denied-despite-chmod-777)