# In java BufferedReader doesn't find a file, even when file exists (and it's existance is confirmed using java)!

Tags: java

I am trying to use `BufferedReader` to read through the lines of a file, but it is giving me a `FileNotFoundException`. After some searching i found a way to check if a file exists (i used this : https://www.javabrahman.com/quick-tips/how-to-check-for-existence-of-a-file-in-java/). It returns true, so the file definitely does exist, and the path is right, however BufferedReader stil can't find it. I've looked at a bunch of possible solutions, but none seem to work.
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
public class neki
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\natan\\Desktop\\words.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String curr="AAAAAA";
        int st=11184810;
        String word; 
        boolean digit=false;
        while(!curr.equals("ffffff"))
        {
            curr=Integer.toHexString(st);
            for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                char c=curr.charAt(i);
                if(Character.isDigit(c))
                {
                    digit=true;
                }
            }
            if(!digit)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<466545;j++)
                    {
                        word=br.readLine();
                        word=word.toLowerCase();
                        if(curr==word)
                        {
                            System.out.println(curr);
                        }
                    }
            }
            st++;
            digit=false;
            Path filePath_1= Paths.get("C:\\Users\\natan\\Desktop\\words.txt");
            boolean fileExists_1= Files.exists(filePath_1);
            System.out.println("File 'bleh' exists: "+fileExists_1);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to call the _exists()_ method of the _file_ before passing it to the FileInputStream?

Comment: I'd be suspicious of that fact that you are using File to get the file for one method, but Paths to get it for another. Can't say I'm too familiar with either, but seems all too likely that they don't work quite the same.

Comment: @obermillerk Don't take this as given (it is a bit more complicated) , but they are pretty interchangeable. This should not be the problem. Although, i also would highly recommend using the Paths-API instead of the File-API.

Comment: Check permissions of the parent folders https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008976/java-io-filenotfoundexception-permission-denied-despite-chmod-777

Answer (score 3):

These paths are not the same, one has 'test\' in the path, and the other doesn't.

`new File("C:\\Users\\natan\\Desktop\\test\\words.txt");`
`Paths.get("C:\\Users\\natan\\Desktop\\words.txt");`

Using a constant to hold static values referenced in multiple places can prevent this kind of error.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, the difference in file paths wasn't there originally and i added it cause i was trying to fix the issue and forgot to change it back in the question. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Natanšemrl Does this mean that this answer is correct, or that this answer is not suitable?

Comment: It is not a suitable answers.