# Weird "Permission denied" when using FileReader

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to read a file with FileReader

```
try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(logFile.getAbsolutePath())) {
    fileReader.read();
}
```

and it says:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
  /u01/app/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/managed/logs/managed.out (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at org.reaction.worker.log.LogReader.checkReadable(LogReader.java:98)
```

The **root** user can read this file in shell.
Also the permissions of the file are as follow:

```
ls -la /u01/app/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/managed/logs/managed.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 16486 Feb 28 17:00 /u01/app/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/managed/logs/managed.out
```

The user **root** executes the code, I checked the value of the *user.name* property in Java which is *root* (`System.getProperty("user.name")`).

Also just to make sure I executed a *cat* command on this file in Java (`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /u01/app/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/managed/logs/managed.out");`) which ran fine.

Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: No problem, thank you! I updated my post.

Comment: Please check this question if it helps you here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008976/java-io-filenotfoundexception-permission-denied-despite-chmod-777. It looks like Java needs other permissions (execution right on directories) whereas your  check with `cat` executes a console command which itself can behave differently.

Comment: It says `FileNotFoundException` as if the file doesn't exist? Maybe you're deleting the file and recreating it at some point?

Comment: @ChatterOne That's just the exception used. The important part, in this context, is the exception message "_path_ (Permission denied)".

Comment: Use the [java.nio.file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package instead.  It provides much more informative exceptions.  For instance, `Reader fileReader = Files.newBufferedReader(logFile.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset())`

Comment: Tom is right, I had to add execution permission to the folders where the file resides and now it works. Thanks for all the comments! @Tom, could you please add your comment as a reply and I will accept it!

Comment: Vikor, no, in this case it is better to mark this question as a duplicate of the other question, so it can work as a sign post for other users who are looking for a solution.

Comment: ok, makes sense! Thanks for the help!